# What should I Py_INCREF?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, gdb, setuptools

I try to design a wrapper in python of CPP files.

Here is my cpp files content:

Foo.cpp:

```cpp
class Foo:
{

cv::Mat mat_;
 Foo();
 void process ( cv::Mat & mat)
  {
  mat.copyTo(mat_);
 ///// Do something

 return;
   }
};
```

In my wrapper file:

```cpp
///....

Foo *foo;

`
bool module_core_init(std::string vision_module_path) {
 ////
  ////
  foo = new Foo();
  return true;
}

bool module_core_setup( cv::Mat reference_image) {

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  foo->process(reference_image);
  return true;
}


#if (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000)
#ifndef NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL
#define NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL NULL
#endif
static void *init_ar() {
#else
#ifndef NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL
#define NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL
#endif
static void init_ar() {
#endif
  Py_Initialize();

  import_array();
  return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(vmpbcvt) {
  // using namespace XM;
  init_ar();

.....
  def("init", module_core_init);
  def("extract_image_signature", module_core_setup);

}

}
```

My question is where should I put "Py_INCREF" on my example ?

I have segmentaion fault on my python call of the cpp functions. It could happens anywhere in the cpp program.

I try to debug the cpp code with gdb but I don't known how to do this.

I use setuptools to generate the python library.

Edit:

I try to debug the segment fault with GDB. So in the setup.py file I add the parameter gdb_debug=True.

```
gdb python3.8-dbg
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from python3.8-dbg...
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) run try_vision_module_interface.py 
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3.8-dbg 
try_module_interface.py
warning: Cannot exec /usr/bin/zsh
warning:  -c
warning:  exec /usr/bin/python3.8-dbgmodule_interface.py
warning: Error: No such file or directory
During startup program exited with code 127.
```

I also try to attach the PID:

```
gdb -pid 128031
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 128031
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
(gdb) r
Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
```

Edit2:
I finally get a trace in gdb:

```
gdb) where
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
#1  0x00007fff3a74806d in QCoreApplication::arguments() () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007fff34f258f1 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#3  0x00007fff34f263d3 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007fff348bf41c in _SmcProcessMessage () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
#5  0x00007fff348ade96 in IceProcessMessages () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6
#6  0x00007fff3a7701d0 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007fff3a77ceb5 in QSocketNotifier::activated(int, QSocketNotifier::QPrivateSignal) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007fff3a77d211 in QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007fff39f8da66 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#10 0x00007fff39f970f0 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#11 0x00007fff3a74480a in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007fff3a79d095 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007fffba49217d in g_main_context_dispatch () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007fffba492400 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007fffba4924a3 in g_main_context_iteration () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007fffbb625061 in QtOpenCVPython::QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QtOpenCVPython::QFlags<QtOpenCVPython::QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/../opencv_python.libs/libQt5Core-d92f2856.so.5.15.0
#17 0x00007fffbfb9c217 in  () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#18 0x00007fffbfba9b3e in  () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#19 0x00007fffbfba9d50 in  () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#20 0x00007fffbfbaa794 in  () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#21 0x00007fffbfbaab3c in  () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#22 0x00007fffbfb97d06 in  () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#23 0x00007fffbed7ffb8 in  () at /home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#24 0x0000000000436672 in cfunction_call_varargs (func=0x7fffc26294d0, args=0x7fffba0ecc80, kwargs=0x0) at ../Objects/call.c:743
#25 0x0000000000439240 in PyCFunction_Call (func=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, kwargs=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/call.c:773
#26 0x00000000004370bf in _PyObject_MakeTpCall
    (callable=callable@entry=0x7fffc26294d0, args=args@entry=0x65a4740, nargs=<optimized out>, keywords=keywords@entry=0x0)
    at ../Objects/call.c:159
#27 0x00000000004eba14 in _PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=9223372036854775810, args=0x65a4740, callable=0x7fffc26294d0)
    at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:125
#28 call_function (kwnames=0x0, oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=<synthetic pointer>, tstate=0x957020) at ../Python/ceval.c:4963
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#29 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=0x65a4540, throwflag=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:3469
#30 0x00000000004df6b9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=f@entry=0x65a4540, throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:741
#31 0x00000000004362b0 in function_code_fastcall (co=<optimized out>, args=0x9c0ef0, nargs=0, globals=<optimized out>)
    at ../Objects/call.c:284
#32 0x0000000000436d56 in _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    (func=<optimized out>, stack=<optimized out>, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/call.c:411
#33 0x00000000004ebdb9 in _PyObject_Vectorcall (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=9223372036854775808, args=0x9c0ef0, callable=0x7fff360e1190)
    at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:127
#34 call_function (kwnames=0x0, oparg=<optimized out>, pp_stack=<synthetic pointer>, tstate=0x957020) at ../Python/ceval.c:4963
#35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=0x9c0d80, throwflag=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:3500
#36 0x00000000004df6b9 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=f@entry=0x9c0d80, throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:741
#37 0x00000000004e01c6 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
    (_co=0x7ffff75025f0, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=argcount@entry=0, kwnames=0x0, kwargs=0x0, kwcount=0, kwstep=2, defs=0x0, defcount=0, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0, name=0x0, qualname=0x0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4298
#38 0x00000000004e032f in PyEval_EvalCodeEx
    (_co=_co@entry=0x7ffff75025f0, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, locals=locals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, args=args@entry=0x0, argcount=argcount@entry=0, kws=kws@entry=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4327
#39 0x00000000004e0361 in PyEval_EvalCode
    (co=co@entry=0x7ffff75025f0, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, locals=locals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650) at ../Python/ceval.c:718
#40 0x0000000000524203 in run_eval_code_obj
    (co=co@entry=0x7ffff75025f0, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, locals=locals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1166
#41 0x0000000000524624 in run_mod
    (mod=mod@entry=0xa1e410, filename=filename@entry=0x7ffff759e120, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, locals=locals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffffffd908, arena=arena@entry=0x7ffff7401340) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1188
#42 0x0000000000527434 in pyrun_file
    (fp=fp@entry=0x955290, filename=filename@entry=0x7ffff759e120, start=start@entry=257, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, locals=locals@entry=0x7ffff75c5650, closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=0x7fffffffd908) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1085
#43 0x000000000052768d in pyrun_simple_file
    (fp=fp@entry=0x955290, filename=filename@entry=0x7ffff759e120, closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffffffd908)
    at ../Python/pythonrun.c:439
#44 0x00000000005277f5 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags
    (fp=fp@entry=0x955290, filename=filename@entry=0x7ffff754b5a0 "try_vision_module_interface.py", closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffffffd908) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:472
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#45 0x00000000005278a4 in PyRun_AnyFileExFlags
    (fp=fp@entry=0x955290, filename=0x7ffff754b5a0 "try_vision_module_interface.py", closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffffffd908) at ../Python/pythonrun.c:90
#46 0x000000000042795a in pymain_run_file (config=config@entry=0x956040, cf=cf@entry=0x7fffffffd908) at ../Modules/main.c:385
#47 0x00000000004281ca in pymain_run_python (exitcode=exitcode@entry=0x7fffffffd93c) at ../Modules/main.c:610
#48 0x0000000000428222 in Py_RunMain () at ../Modules/main.c:689
#49 0x0000000000428277 in pymain_main (args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd980) at ../Modules/main.c:719
#50 0x00000000004282fb in Py_BytesMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ../Modules/main.c:743
#51 0x0000000000426de3 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ../Programs/python.c:16
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#objects-types-and-reference-counts and https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html ?

Comment: Thank you for the links. I red it. My main question is about my variable Foo *foo, should I use Py_XINCREF on it and on its pointers ?